# Name of day of week in italian language in c#

Tags: c#, dayofweek

I can't to extract the name of day of week in italian language in my aspx page with c#.

I have tried this solution but in the output I have Friday, what wrong?

```
DateTime ItalianJobCookie = DateTime.Parse(Request.Cookies["ItalianJob"].Value);
string ItalianJobCookieDayName = ItalianJobCookie.DayOfWeek.ToString("G", new CultureInfo("it-IT"));

Response.Write(ItalianJobCookieDayName.ToString());
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`DateTime.DayOfWeek` returns a `DayOfWeek` of a given DateTime which has no `ToString` that supports different cultures. This is even [documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dayofweek(v=vs.110).aspx):

> The members of the DayOfWeek enumeration **are not localized**. To return
>   the localized name of the day of the week, **call the
>   DateTime.ToString(String) or the DateTime.ToString(String,
>   IFormatProvider) method** with either the "ddd" or "dddd" format
>   strings. The former format string produces the abbreviated weekday
>   name; the latter produces the full weekday name.

Instead use it with `DateTime`

```
string ItalianJobCookieDayName = ItalianJobCookie.ToString("dddd");
```

if the current culture is italian, otherwise:

```
string ItalianJobCookieDayName = ItalianJobCookie.ToString("dddd", new CultureInfo("it-IT"));
```

If you want the abbreviated day-name use `ddd` instead of `dddd`. [Further informations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.100).aspx).

Answer (score 4):

[`DayOfWeek`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dayofweek%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is culture invariant. It's always returns *english-based* day names.

From documentation;

> The members of the DayOfWeek enumeration **are not localized.** To return
>   the localized name of the day of the week, call the
>   DateTime.ToString(String) or the DateTime.ToString(String,
>   IFormatProvider) method with either the **"ddd"** or **"dddd"** format
>   strings. The former format string produces the abbreviated weekday
>   name; the latter produces the full weekday name.

You need to use [`dddd` format specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx#ddddSpecifier) with `it-IT` culture.

```
string ItalianJobCookieDayName = ItalianJobCookie.ToString("dddd", new CultureInfo("it-IT"));
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, replace this:

```
string ItalianJobCookieDayName = 
ItalianJobCookie.DayOfWeek.ToString("G", new CultureInfo("it-IT"));
```

with this:

```
string ItalianJobCookieDayName = 
new CultureInfo("it-IT").DateTimeFormat.GetDayName(ItalianJobCookie.DayOfWeek);
```